# Rotating proxies using RestTemplate

Tags: java, spring, rest, proxy

I define a proxy in my configuration file of a Spring application following

```
    @Bean
    public RestTemplate restTemplate() {
        SimpleClientHttpRequestFactory requestFactory = new SimpleClientHttpRequestFactory();

        Proxy proxy= new Proxy(Proxy.Type.HTTP, new InetSocketAddress("my.host.com", 8080));
        requestFactory.setProxy(proxy);

        return new RestTemplate(requestFactory);
    }
```

Is there any way that I can set more than one proxy so that when I access the autowired restTemplate it uses a different one every time other that making my own implementation of requestFactory?

Comment: Can't you make the restTemplate request scope?

Comment: Nope, big parallelization would cause escalability problems, abusing resources

Comment: Then don't autowire the restTemplate at all. Create an instance on fly. If necessary you can store the instances in a map where key is somehow the proxy and value is the restTemplate.